# How to display an error message of a select field in laravel

Tags: laravel

I was trying to validate a form, but it seems that I cant show the error message for the dropdown field.

here is my updade.blade.php

```
<div class="form-group">
<select id="province" name="province" class="form-control @error('province') is-invalid @enderror" >
                                        <option>Choose...</option>
                                        <option value="Western Cape" {{ ($user->learner->province == "Western Cape") ? 'selected' : ''}}>Western Cape</option>
                                        <option value="Northern Cape" {{ ($user->learner->province == "Northern Cape") ? 'selected' : '' }}>Northern Cape</option>
                                        <option value="Eastern Cape" {{ ($user->learner->province == "Eastern Cape") ? 'selected' : '' }}>Eastern Cape</option>
                                        <option value="North West" {{ ($user->learner->province == "North West") ? 'selected' : '' }}>North West</option>
                                        <option value="Free State" {{ ($user->learner->province == "Free State") ? 'selected' : '' }}> Free State</option>
                                        <option value="Kwazulu Natal" {{ ($user->learner->province == "Kwazulu Natal") ? 'selected' : '' }}>Kwazulu Natal</option>
                                        <option value="Gauteng" {{ ($user->learner->province == "Gauteng") ? 'selected' : '' }}>Gauteng</option>
                                        <option value="Limpopo" {{ ($user->learner->province == "Limpopo") ? 'selected' : '' }}>Limpopo</option>
                                        <option value="Mpumalanga" {{ ($user->learner->province == "Mpumalanga") ? 'selected' : '' }}>Mpumalanga</option>
                                    </select>
                                    @error('province')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
```

and here is the update method from the UserController

```
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'email' => 'email',
            'phone' => 'min:10|max:15',
            'gender' => 'required',
            'identity' => 'required',
            'password' => 'string|min:8|confirmed',
            'street' => 'required',
            'suburb' => 'required',
            'city' => 'required',            
            'province' => 'required|not_in:0',
            'code' => 'required',
            'school' => 'required',
            'grade' => 'required|not_in:0'
        ]);
    
        $user = User::find($id);
        $user->update($request->all());

           if($user->types == 'Learner'){
            $learner = Learner::where('user_id',$id)->first();
            $learner->gender = $request->input('gender');
            $learner->identity = $request->input('identity');
            $learner->street = $request->input('street');
            $learner->suburb = $request->input('suburb');
            $learner->city = $request->input('city');
            $learner->province = $request->input('province');
            $learner->code = $request->input('code');
            $learner->school = $request->input('school');
            $learner->grade = $request->input('grade');
            $learner->save();
            return redirect()->back()->with('message','User Updated Successfully');
           }
}
```

I want the error message to be displayed at the bottom of the select field and the field to have a red border around... Its working fine for other input fields but the problem is the select field...

Comment: Are you using any java script libraries like `select2` for your select element?

Comment: No Im not using any a javascript library... should I be using one?

Comment: No. I mean if you were using javascript libraries like `select2` they hide the actual dom element and populate their own elements. If you are not using the libraries then it won't be the problem.

Comment: Remove the name='province' from your form your select tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `province` validation is failing. You're asking Laravel to validate that your province is not the value `0`. If you don't choose an option, the value of your `select` element is actually 'Choose...' which is not 0 and therefore not failing.

If you set the 'Choose...' option value to be `value="0"` your rule will pass and you'll see an error message.

```
<option value="0">Choose...</option>
```

For more information on the `not_in` validation rule, [check the Laravel validation docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-not-in).

Comment: Good... Now is it the same for Checkbox or Radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify an empty value for `Choose...` option.
because you use required validation for `province`

```
<option value="">Choose...</option>
```